# Trying to create instagram bot but, keep getting sytax error?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

iam trying to create an instagram bot, but i keep getting an syntax error i think?
i have the code and logs posted. If someone could help me out would be much appreciated. Iam writing the code with puppeteer and javascript.

i have some experience with coding but this language is totally new for me and followed a tutorial on youtube, somehow i dont know how to get rid of the error.

it says the error is at line 46

**This is the Puppeteer code**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/';
const TAG_URL = (tag) => 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/${tag}/';
const instagram = {
  browser: null,
  page: null,
  initialize: async() => {
    instagram.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    });
    instagram.page = await instagram.browser.newPage();
  },
  login: async(username, password) => {
    await instagram.page.goto(BASE_URL, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
    let loginButton = await instagram.page.$x('//a[contains(text(), "Meld je dan aan")]');
    /*Click on the login url button */
    await loginButton[0].click();
    //await instagram.page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await instagram.page.waitFor(2000);
    /* Username en password */
    await instagram.page.type('input[name="username"]', username, {
      delay: 50
    });
    await instagram.page.type('input[name="password"]', password, {
      delay: 50
    });
    /* click login button */
    await instagram.page.waitFor(2000);
    loginButton = await instagram.page.$x('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button/div');
    await loginButton[0].click();
  },
  likeTagsProcess = async(tags = []) => {
    for (let tag of tags) {
      // go to the tag page
      await instagram.page.goto(TAG_URL(tag), {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
      });
      await instagram.page.waitFor(1000);
      let posts = await instagram.page.$$('article > div:nth-child(3) img[decoding="auto"]');
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let post = posts[i];
        await post.click();
        await instagram.page.waitFor('span[id="react-root"][aria-hidden="true"]');
        await instagram.page.waitFor(1000);
        let isLikeable = await instagram.page.$('span[aria-label="Vind ik leuk"]');
        if (islikeable) {
          await instagram.page.click('span[aria-label="Vind ik leuk"]');
        }
        await instagram.page.waitFor(3000);
        // sluiten foto 
        let closeModelButton = await instagram.page.$x('//button[contains(text(), "Sluiten")]');
        await closeModelButton[0].click();
        await instagram.page.waitFor(1000);
      }
      await instagram.page.waitFor(60000);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = instagram;
```

**And here are the logs of the debugger**

```
\Desktop\instabot2\instagram.js:46
    likeTagsProcess = async (tags = []) => {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\31613\Desktop\instabot2\index.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? You're still inside an object, that should be : not =. Compare it to login, which you defined just before.

Comment: yes i did read the error message, what do you mean with iam still inside an object? should the liketagsprocess be a completely new object?

Comment: Look at “login” and “initialize”

Comment: Just compare likeTagsProcess to the other four things you define as part of the Instagram object. I mean you're still part-way through a literal object definition. I don't know if it should be a new object, that's up to your needs, but as the message says it's not valid syntax like that.

Comment: aah thank you got it to work, i changed liketagsprocess = async to: liketagsprocess: async!